# Removing arbitrary characters in php

Tags: php

Please see the following code. I want to remove all the unauthorized characters such as `. / \ | !@#$%^&*() _ - = + ~  < > , ? : ; " ' [] { }` and the ` character and and all the empty spaces input.

I want receive only English characters  and Numbers allowed.

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
   $username = test_input($_POST["user"]);
   $password = test_input($_POST["pass"]);}
```

How should be the `test_input()` function?

Comment: Especially for authentication: *do not remove characters from the user's input*! Or your business risks being [ridiculed and made example of online](http://www.jeremytunnell.com/posts/swab-password-policies-and-two-factor-authentication-a-comedy-of-errors), leading to loss of users. Imagine your user wants `-_-; \*_*/` as password. You apply your `test_input`, and the password ends up saved as an empty string. I can then log in as them using `~~~~~~~` for password. That's not a security hole, that's a security *canyon*. If you really don't want them, warn the user, then refuse input.

Answer (score 0):

```
function test_input($string){
    if(preg_match('/[^a-z_\-0-9]/i', $string))
    {
      echo "not valid string";
    }
}
```